# Translate iPhone App to Chinese

Tags: ios, xcode, translate

Im making an app for a client who has asked if I can make a Chinese version for him, or add a translate button within the app to make everything Chinese. Is there a way to do this within Xcode, or some way to take the phones language and translate the app?

Comment: You can add support for different languages fairly easily with XCode, I suggest you do a google search and you will find it very fast, no point explaining it again myself

Comment: This whole process is called Localization...look it up.

Comment: been looking, kept getting info about changing code languages, all i needed was someone to say search Localization, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that is making your app Localizable.
To do that:

1. Create a file named Localizable.strings (the name and the type are important);
2. Select the created file and press the "Make localized..." button on the right pane (File Inspector);
3. Select English and click "Localize";
4. Go to your Project Info tab;
5. There is a new item on this page named "Localizations", click the "+" icon and select Chinese;
6. Select the items you want to localize. Here I suggest let only the created file Localizable.strings and click Finish;
7. You will see a indicator in your Localizable.strings that let you expand. Do it;
8. You will see two files: one for English and another for Chinese. You have to put your text in both with a identifier. Here's an example:

   //English
   "start" = "Start:";
   "end" = "End:";
   "new" = "New";

   //Chinese
   "start" = "TextInChinese:";
   "end" = "TextInChinese:";
   "new" = "TextInChinese";
9. In order to access these information in your code, you have to use the following code:

_variable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"start", @"Some Coment you want to use")];

That will do the job you want.

Comment: It's not as simple as that, for an app to be truly localized, you need to take into account Locales (for number and date formatting) etc.. Whilst this will be done automatically if you've used formatters correctly, you've got to take into account the scenarios where they haven't. Localization is a very broad topic, and covers much more that String replacement based on language (NIBs can also be complicated with Localization pre-iOS 6).

Comment: Agreed... but it's something that he can look and have a place to start. Searching docs and the web for more info and more complete tasks that he can do is mandatory!

Answer (score 1):

Your question covers a large scope, and as such a detailed answer can't be provided.

Internationalization and Localization isn't a simple task. I suggest reading through the documentation, and using the examples and resources Apple provide. Specifically look at **Programming Resources**. https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate someone giving me a place to start other than Google it.